# Is there a name for this higher order function?

Tags: f#

I very frequently want to apply the same argument twice to a binary function `f`, is there a name for this `convert` function/combinator?

```
// convert: f: ('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b
let convert f x = f x x
```

Example usage might be partially applying `convert` with the multiplication operator `*` to fix the multiplicand and multiplier:

```
let fixedMultiplication = convert (*)

fixedMultiplication 2 // returns 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That combinator is usually called a `warbler`; the name comes from Raymond Smullyan's book [To Mock a Mockingbird](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0192801422), which has a bunch of logic puzzles around combinator functions, presented in the form of birds that can imitate each other's songs. See [this usage](https://suave.io/composing.html) in Suave, and [this page](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/combinator/birds.html) which lists a whole bunch of combinator functions (the "standard" ones and some less-well-known ones as well), and the names that Smullyan gave them in his book.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to what it's called in F#, but in [APL](http://www.dyalog.com/blog/2015/10/the-reflexcommute-operator/) or [J](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Reflexive), it's called the "reflexive" (or perhaps "reflex") operator. In APL it is spelt `⍨` and used monadically – i.e. applied to one function (on its left). In J it's called `~`, and used in the same way.

For example: `f⍨ x` is equivalent to `x f x` (in APL, functions that take two arguments are always used in a binary infix fashion).

So the "fixedMultiplication" (or square) function is `×⍨` in APL, or `*~` in J.

Answer (score 1):

This is the monadic `join` operator for functions. `join` has type

```
Monad m => m (m a) => m a
```

and functions form a monad where the input type is fixed (i.e. `((->) a`), so `join` has type:

```
(a -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)
```